# StartActivity on Fragment

Tags: android

I have read all the old questions asked about this, but I have not found a solution that works for me. I am going crazy. The following are all the codes I've tried, no one works.

1.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listner OnClik sul bottone "Cerca"             

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) { //OnClick                    
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //Creo il bundle
                    Log.d("4","ok");
                    bundle.putString("dati", camporicerca.getText().toString()); //Metto nel parametro "dati" il testo nel campo di ricerca
                    Log.d("5","ok");
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Risultato.class); //Istanzio l'activity
                    Log.d("6","ok");   
                    in.putExtras(bundle); //Passo il payload all'activity
                    Log.d("7","ok");   
                    startActivity(in); //Avvio l'activity   
                    Log.d("8","ok");
                }

            });
```

2.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listner OnClik sul bottone "Cerca"             

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) { //OnClick                    
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //Creo il bundle
                    Log.d("4","ok");
                    bundle.putString("dati", camporicerca.getText().toString()); //Metto nel parametro "dati" il testo nel campo di ricerca
                    Log.d("5","ok");
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Risultato.class); //Istanzio l'activity
                    Log.d("6","ok");   
                    in.putExtras(bundle); //Passo il payload all'activity
                    Log.d("7","ok");   
                    getActivity().startActivity(in); //Avvio l'activity 
                    Log.d("8","ok");
                }

            });
```

3.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listner OnClik sul bottone "Cerca"             

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) { //OnClick                    
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //Creo il bundle
                        Log.d("4","ok");
                        bundle.putString("dati", camporicerca.getText().toString()); //Metto nel parametro "dati" il testo nel campo di ricerca
                        Log.d("5","ok");
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Risultato.class); //Istanzio l'activity
                        Log.d("6","ok");   
                        in.putExtras(bundle); //Passo il payload all'activity
                        Log.d("7","ok");   
                        getActivity().startActivity(in); //Avvio l'activity 
                        Log.d("8","ok");
                    }

                });
```

4.

```
   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listner OnClik sul bottone "Cerca"              

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) { //OnClick                    
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //Creo il bundle
                    Log.d("4","ok");
                    bundle.putString("dati", camporicerca.getText().toString()); //Metto nel parametro "dati" il testo nel campo di ricerca
                    Log.d("5","ok");
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Risultato.class); //Istanzio l'activity
                    Log.d("6","ok");   
                    in.putExtras(bundle); //Passo il payload all'activity
                    Log.d("7","ok");   
                    startActivity(in); //Avvio l'activity   
                    Log.d("8","ok");
                }

            });
```

And other variants found searching on Google.

This is the LogCat

```
12-27 09:31:34.991: D/4(1054): ok
12-27 09:31:34.991: D/5(1054): ok
12-27 09:31:35.001: D/6(1054): ok
12-27 09:31:35.001: D/7(1054): ok
12-27 09:31:35.001: I/ActivityManager(381): START u0 {cmp=com.example.android.effectivenavigation/.Risultato (has extras)} from pid 1054
12-27 09:31:35.021: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.021: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.021: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.031: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.031: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.031: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.041: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.051: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.051: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.051: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.051: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.051: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.061: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.061: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.061: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.061: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.071: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.071: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.071: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.071: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
12-27 09:31:35.071: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
```

Why doesn't works? Any solutions?

Comment: Are you working with Fragment or Activity??

Comment: Your stack trace is not showing actual issue.. please check in logcat where actual exception is explained and re-post logcat

Comment: wants to call another Activity on fragment??

Comment: Yes, I want to start activity from fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really necessary to start activity from Fragment?
I haven't tried code you have shared in Question. but you can achieve this as follows

1. Create Fragment

   ```
   public class ClickFragment extends Fragment{
          << Fragment related code>>
   }
   ```
2. Create one interface which has method for calling another activity with Bundle object as parameter eg. callSecondActivity(Bundle bundle)

   ```
   public interface FragmentCoordinator{

        void callSecondActivity(Bundle bundle);

   }
   ```
3. implement this interface in your Activity class

   ```
   public class YourActivity extends Activity implements FragmentCoordinator {

     <<< Activity related code>>>

   @Override
   public void callSecondActivity(Bundle bundle){
       Intent in = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Risultato.class);
       in.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(in);
   }
   ```

Add following code in your current Fragment

```
     public class ClickFragment extends Fragment{
           << Fragment related code>>

         submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listner OnClik sul bottone "Cerca"              

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) { //OnClick                    
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //Creo il bundle

                    bundle.putString("dati", camporicerca.getText().toString()); //Metto nel parametro "dati" il testo nel campo di ricerca
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
            FragmentCoordinator coordinator = (FragmentCoordinator)activity;
            coordinator.callSecondActivity(bundle);
                }

            });
    }
```

Comment: Breakpoint at FragmentCoordinator coordinator = (FragmentCoordinator)activity;

Comment: Maybe the problem is: my mainactivity extends FragmentActivity not Activity, so your code don't works...

Comment: Yes that could be issue

Comment: Solved: public class Risultato extends FragmentActivity. 
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Hi, If you think answer above is right one .. you can accept this as an answer or please post your answer which  will help me and others to tackle with similar issues